# How to get the Id from Gridview of Chechbox.checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView and a button as follows. Then i am binding the gridview with data from my database. GridView has two hiddenfield for Id and ClassIndex.
when i selecting a  checkbox and click button, i want to get the corresponding Id and FileName.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="check" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfId" runat ="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfClssIndex" runat ="server" Value='<%#Eval("ClassIndex") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and Button Like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Send Request" />
```

the code behind button is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
       var check = row.FindControl("check") as CheckBox;
       if (check.Checked)
       {
         int Id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);
         //some logic follws here
       }
    }
}
```

but i am getting an error like

Input string was not in a correct format.
What is the error and how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping correct.

But you forgot to notice one thing here, when you wanted to access `CheckBox` you did a `FindControl` on `row`. Which means you are trying to find some control in that row.

Then why are you accessing `HiddenField` control inside row with `row.Cell[1].Text`?
Try to find that also.

`int Id = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdfId")).Value);`

Comment: Thanks. Now i got :) But i don't have much reputation to up vote it :(

Comment: Any ideas how to access the `ID` without a `HiddenField`, possibly by going up the tree and locating the row's `ID` cell and retiree the id from it?

Comment: @w.m. you can set `DataKeyNames` property and value can be accessed through `DataKeys`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx