# How to call id from gridview in javascript window.open in asp .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm new to .net and jquery.

My gridview shows like this http://s3.postimg.org/erfrxh25f/untitled.jpg

Here is my loginfo click event.

```
protected void loginfo_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)(sender);
    Response.Write("<script>");
    Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + + "','_blank')");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Book_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="240px" 
        Width="755px" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="2px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_id" HeaderText="Book_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book_id" >
            <ControlStyle BorderColor="Red" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_name" HeaderText="Book_name" SortExpression="Book_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Author_name" HeaderText="Author_name" SortExpression="Author_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher_name" HeaderText="Publish_name" SortExpression="Publisher_name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle BorderColor="#CCFF66" BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Book_id") %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
              <ControlStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log Info">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnloginfo" Text="Log-Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Book_id") %>' Onclick="loginfo_click"/>
               </ItemTemplate>
              <ControlStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BorderColor="Red" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF0066" BorderColor="#CCFFFF" ForeColor="White" 
            Height="50px" Width="50px" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I just confused how to call bookid in window.open.,

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**update:**

loginfo.css:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_logdetails", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        }
```

loginfo.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Book_id" EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White"  Height="240px" 
        Width="755px" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="2px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book_id" >
            <ControlStyle BorderColor="Red" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bookid" HeaderText="bookid" SortExpression="bookid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="studentid" HeaderText="studentid" SortExpression="studentid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="returndate" HeaderText="returndate" SortExpression="returndate" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="returnstatus" HeaderText="returnstatus" SortExpression="returnstatus" />

            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: `txtbookid.Text` not working?

Comment: Actually I'm new .. so i don't know how to write?

Comment: `Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + txtbookid.Text.Trim() + "','_blank')");`

Comment: Ok i will try, and let know.. thanks..

Comment: Have you entered any value inside that textbox?

Comment: You could have told this in the question :)

Comment: Check this, do something similar to find your textbox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541717/how-to-get-the-id-from-gridview-of-chechbox-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already setting `Book_id` as a `CommandArgument`, so you can get the value from there directly by accessing the button through `sender` object.

```
protected void loginfo_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Response.Write("<script>");
    Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

Comment: I need to display data in loginfo.aspx page as gridview by callint stored procedure,

Comment: for that what to do, here is the screenshot http://s21.postimg.org/ri0m4w61z/untitled.jpg

Comment: what you have till now? I mean how much coding you done so far for that?

Comment: I don't know how to call storedprocedure 'sp_logdetails' to display data

Comment: can you please see my updated post.. i added loginfo and cs code, but this page shows nothing..can you please help? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973773/stored-procedure-return-into-dataset-in-c-sharp-net this will show about the execution, and resultant `DataSet` you can assign to `DataSource` of the `GridView`.

Comment: in the above link what is TimeRanges?

Comment: answer is having the sample to execute procedure. Understand the code and use it according to your requirement